# 'matlab' is not a package - problem with Pycharm

Tags: python, linux, matlab

I am trying to use 'matlab.engine' in a python script (in Pycharm - Linux).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
print(eng.sqrt(4.0))
```

When I run this script in Pycharm, I get an error indicating that

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlab.engine'; 'matlab' is not a package".
```

[image: The error]

However, when I call this script from the terminal of Linux, it works perfectly (either `python /main.py` or `python3 /main.py` works).

Would it be possible to help me to figure out the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are u using a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, I am using a virtual environment on Pycharm.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text(not screenshot). There are other useful infrmation.

Comment: if you use `virtual environment` then you may have to install it in `virtual environment`. But maybe you created file `matlab.py` and now it can't import module `matlab` because it loads your file `matlab.py`

Comment: @furas, thanks for your reply. I have updated the post with the full error.
I did not get your point about virtual environment. Would you please clarify it for me?

Comment: when you create `virtual environment` then it creates fresh Python without external modules and you have to install (in  `virtual environment`) all modules which you need.

Comment: did you create folder with name `matlab` ?  Python can treat  folder `matlab` as package.

Comment: I can get error `No module named 'matlab.engine'; 'matlab' is not a package` only if I have file `matlab.py` in the same folder as I run code. You may check (before `import matlab.engine`) in which folder it runs `print( os.getcwd() )` (Current Working Directory) and what you have in this folder `print( os.listdir() )`

Comment: Using `print( os.getcwd() )` and `print( os.listdir() )`, I found that I do not have any file named `matlab.py` in my current working directory. My working directory is `/home/amirhossein/Pycharm/PycharmProject` and the folders and files it include are 
`['pyvenv.cfg', 'lib64', 'main.py', 'lib', 'include', 'bin']`. Note that I have a file named `matlab.py` in `/home/amirhossein/Pycharm/PycharmProject/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`.